# How do I run VBA code when all the cells in a table column have a certain value?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to run code in my worksheet when all the cells in a filtered table column contain a certain value. How do I reference the table column instead of a single cell?

I am using Worksheet_Change.

The code works when I am using a single cell value in my range, but when I use  the column reference as my range, I get a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("n2").Value = "P" Then
'If Range("Table1[Verify]").Value = "P" Then

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 5").Visible = True

ElseIf Range("n2").Value <> "P" Then
'ElseIf Range("Table1[Verify]").Value <> "P" Then

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 5").Visible = False

End If

End Sub
```

I expected this to work because I can run the code:

```
Range("Table1[Verify]").Value = "P"
```

and it fills every cell in the filtered column "Verify" with the value "P". Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to loop the range and test, or use `Application.Countif()` and compare that with the number of cells in the range.

Comment: Will this work if I want to use multiple criteria, for example "P" or "Q" in the column cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Range("Table1[Verify]").Value
```

returns a 2-D array of values (# of rows x # of columns) so you cannot compare that with "P".  Only if there's a single visible row would that work (since `.Value` in that case is not an array)

For visible cells only you'd need something like:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("Table1[Verify]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Then loop over every cell in rng and check if "P"

```
Dim c As range
For Each c in rng.Cells
     'check the value
Next c
```

You can't use `application.countif(rng,"P")` unless rng is contiguous